# Best style for initial state that varies.

Tags: javascript, user-interface, reactjs

I'm new to reactJS and want to know if what I am doing is in good style and makes sense.

We have a pretty old app that is written in PHP and uses smarty templates/a mess of jquery for front-end rendering. We have recently started implementing react.js and I'm working on a feature where users can view a list of incomplete candidates. This list depends on a site and a test.

A php script is getting called with requests for site and test. There are functions in this php script that then return an array of the incomplete candidates that a smarty template renders.

Right now I have refactored so in the smarty template there is a div where I've implemented a jsx script tag that contains a panel with a list of incomplete candidates.

My question is two fold:

1. Does it make sense to use "site" and "test" as state and then use some kind of AJAX script to get the array of incomplete candidates or is it in better style to simple set the array of incomplete candidates as state.
2. How can I set this initial state without the use of Ajax? (Is there say a way I pass state directly from PHP to my react.js components or pass a variable from smarty to react.js.

Regarding my first question I think I need a better grasp on state but from my understanding and from what I've read [here](https://github.com/uberVU/react-guide/blob/master/props-vs-state.md): *If a Component needs to alter one of its attributes at some point in time, that attribute should be part of its state, otherwise it should just be a prop for that Component.*

From my point of view this state is the visit and test and it determines what users should be listed.

I would love some input on if my thinking is flawed. I am still wrapping my head around react.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it make sense to use "site" and "test" as state

They should be state if they change at runtime and this component should logically own them (no parent component cares about their current value, or there is no parent component).

They should be instance properties if this component is the logical owner and they don't affect render.

Otherwise: props.

> and then use some kind of AJAX script to get the array of incomplete candidates or is it in better style to simple set the array of incomplete candidates as state

If you need to fetch new data based on changing parameters, ajax is the way to do it. I'm not sure what the question here is, because you say "... or is it in better style to ..." but you'd d the ajax, and then put the result in state.

> How can I set this initial state without the use of Ajax?

You put it in a global variable (json in a script tag), or a data-foo attribute of an element, and the JS reads that and uses it in getInitialState.

---

> where I've implemented a jsx script tag

If you're using JSXTransformer on the client, it has to load a bunch of code which then searches for script tags, tokenizes and parses the scripts to an AST, performs some transformations on the code, generates a string from the modified AST, and then executes it.

It's a good development tool, but isn't intended for production. The alternatives are not using JSX, or compiling it to plain JS ahead of time and having php send that.